# How to base a new model object on an old model object, but allow customization of certain fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to add the capability of basing a new Item on a currently existing item. The new item should have all the older item's tasks, but certain fields should be reset.

The model class method I added (`def self.copy(item)`) below sort of works, but it's only setup to clone an item exactly; I want it to clone some fields, and let the user enter in data for the rest.

For example, when I copy an item, its number is copied as well, but I'd rather give the user a chance to enter a unique number--how do I do this?

Ideally, I'd like to integrate the copy function into the new action on the items controller, so that each time a user creates a new item, they're given the opportunity to base it off another item currently in the database. Does this make sense?

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :department
  belongs_to :item
  belongs_to :customer
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :tasks

  def self.copy(item)
    newitem = item.clone
    newitem.tasks << item.tasks.map(&:clone)
    return newitem
  end
end
```

Comment: Are the "some fields" going to be the same every time?

Comment: yes, they will be the same each time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will create a new item with everything but the field 'item_number' copied.

```
def self.copy(old_item)    
  Item.new(old_item.attributes.merge({:item_number => nil}))
end
```

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. How do you suggest I go about allowing the user to enter in a custom :item_number ?

Comment: Would this go into the controller? How would I make a link to this?